# FreeSwitch outgoing call. Answering machine(fax) detection

Tags: voip, freeswitch, fusionpbx

Is there a way to detect and log calling on fax machines somehow to see the number of 'real'(human-human) calls and 'false'(human-fax) ones before someone answers the call?

I've searched for solutions and found possible ones:

- spandsp_start_fax_detect.
  `<action application="spandsp_start_fax_detect" data="transfer 'fax XML default' 3"/>`
- tone_detect.
  `<action application="tone_detect" data="busy 425 r 0 hangup 'normal_clearing' 3"/>`
- mod_com_amd module

I'm not sure that these solutions are the ones I need, and AMD module costs 50$ per channel, so I'm asking for help.
Using FusionPBX(FreeSwitch).

Does anyone know the correct way of resolving the problem?

Answer (score 1):

> before someone answers the call?

There is no way to detect if its a fax machine or Human before answering a call.

`tone_detect` and `spandsp` are the ones in freeswitch to detect fax - Free module

I've 90% success rate in detecting fax calls with

`<action application="tone_detect" data="fax 1100 r +5000 transfer 'faxreceive XML fax' 1"/>`

Check for the params explanation [here](https://wiki.freeswitch.org/wiki/Misc._Dialplan_Tools_tone_detect)